# Unable to get Genymotion working in VMWare

Tags: cordova, opengl, virtualbox, vmware, genymotion

I use genymotion to test my android app -created by cordova-. I tried to work with it in my vmware (v12, all tools updated, drivers inclusive; windows 7 enterprise). But after setting up the device, when i run the device, i encounter with the following screen:

[image]

Should i do something special to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had still not a go.

[from their faq](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=virtual-machine-start-impossible#faq):

**Why doesn't Genymotion start from a virtual machine?**

Genymotion cannot be run from a virtual machine.
Indeed, Genymotion needs a direct access to the hardware in order to provide OpenGL acceleration. Running Genymotion from a virtual machine prevents it to directly access the hardware components.
Therefore, Genymotion is incompatible when installed from VMWare, Parallels, Hyper-V or VirtualPC.